# Android Sharing a Google Map V2 itinerary (Facebook)

Tags: android, facebook, sharing, google-maps-android-api-2

I developed an Android application that allows real-time trace of a course made ​​by the user on a map (Google Map Android V2), I'd do next is that after the end of the course I want to give the user the opportunity to share this itinerary on Facebook for example, I do not know if it is possible, if so I will need your help because after my research the only way to do this is through a screenshot of the map but I've seen applications that do this kind of sharing and the result is not an image but a map (Bring in the case of Facebook) itinerary.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it through Open Graph, and create an object with a set of GeoPoints for your route.

The exact details are too dense for a StackOverflow answer, but I would encourage you to read through the docs here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ and more specifically something like https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/fitness/ which fits more closely to what you're looking for.